# Pre Build Event: Copy Files and include in project using XCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have an asp.net MVC web application, and I have some plugin. I want to copy some files from plugins projects to the main project. here my pre-build event comment:

```
xcopy /C /E /F /R /Y /I "$(SolutionDir)PluginLayer\$(ProjectName)\Areas\StreamVideo\Views" "$(SolutionDir)PresentLayer\Delta.Ecommerce\Plugins\StreamVideo\Areas\StreamVideo\Views"
xcopy /C /E /F /R /Y /I "$(SolutionDir)PluginLayer\$(ProjectName)\Scripts" "$(SolutionDir)PresentLayer\Delta.Ecommerce\Plugins\StreamVideo\Scripts"
```

It's work great. But I need to include folders to project for web deploy. But with this command, I just copy files and folders and not included to project but project work great and my plugins work well. but when I want to use the publish button in the menu not included this files and folders, but when I include files and folders in solution explorer it's work great and when I push the publish button include it in publish folder.
I want to do this with code and automatically and I don't want include files and folders each time on my own

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should help you. Check it out. http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,b352f04a-2449-4cbb-8125-7acdef9552e1.aspx

Comment: @dj79 Thank you.